# angularjs ng-repeat is not working to owl-carousel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, owl-carousel

I'm running into an issue where whenever the ng-repeat directive is applied to carousel the items are stacked vertically instead of being layout horizontally.

**Screenshot for reference**

[After Applying ng-repeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPNTj.jpg)

If I leave out ng-repeat and use static items then it works as it should.

[When used static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBqhz.png)

**HTML Code for ng-repeat**

```html
<section class="mp diff-types-section main-movies-position">

  <div class="mp our-recommend-sec">
    <div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel" ng-repeat="movie in movieList">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="types-section">
          <img class="types-section-image image-opacity" ng-src="/public/uploads/{{movie.movieId}}/backdrop.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**AngularJs Controller Code**

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$resource', '$route', '$state', '$location', 'localStorageService', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $resource, $route, $state, $location, localStorageService) {
  $rootScope.showNav = true;
  $rootScope.searchBar = false;

  $scope.getAllMovieList = function() {
    $http.get("/api/getAllMovieList")
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.movieList = response.data;
        console.log($scope.movieList);
      });
  }

  $scope.getAllMovieList();
}])
```

**If I Keep The Static Code Like This its Working Fine with no issues**

```html
<section class="mp diff-types-section our-reccomendation-section">
  <div class=" mp our-recommend-sec">
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="types-section">
          <a ng-click="goToMovieDetail()"> <img class="types-section-image" src="../../images/92ZhAYYce2KfuLgBswzW5HCMKxr.jpg"></a>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="types-section" ng-click="goToMovieDetail()">
          <img class="types-section-image" src="../../images/Shooter_1920x1080.jpg">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class=" types-section" ng-click="goToMovieDetail()">
          <img class="types-section-image" src="/public/uploads/ow168259/backdrop.jpg">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="types-section" ng-click="goToMovieDetail()">
          <img class="types-section-image" src="/public/uploads/ow168259/backdrop.jpg">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Hope I get Solution For this...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try declare `$scope.movieList` as object or array out of `getAllMovieList` function.

Comment: ok ill try.....

Comment: I mean as this `$scope.movieList = [];`

Comment: ok ill let u know

Comment: even now it's not working @Hadi

Comment: did you inject `owl-carousel` angular js file? see [this](https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel)

Comment: yeah.... if i didn't include how can i get carousel when I do Statically....

Comment: [Image](https://ibb.co/e1MHNF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution would be helpful to you

```
 Put owl carousel function after getting response 
 **use Like:** 
 $timeout(function(){ here your owl carousel function },10);
```

Comment: I think your API Response Problem.  

have you get proper from response ?

Answer (score 2):

Owl-carousel may not perfectly work with angularjs, would recommend you to use a carousel which supports angularjs, personally i use [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), it has all components bootstrap has to offer but provides angular variants.